# for loop terminating early when comparing to Integer.MAX_VALUE and using System.out.println

Tags: java, for-loop, int, max

When I run this class the for loop seems to terminate early

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int result = 0;
        int end = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= end; i += 2) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        System.out.println("End:" + i);
    }

}
```

Output is:

```
1
3
5
...
31173
31175
End:31177
```

Why does it end there? Interestingly if I removed the `System.out.println(i)` in the for loop, the output would be `End:-2147483647`. Obviously the value in `i` has `wrapped round`.

The Java version I'm using is

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.2-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Try printing Integer.MAX_VALUE

Comment: I am not getting such output. Seems to be your buffer is filled up or something.

Comment: The code shouldn't ever print End, thats a bug as well(albeit a slightly different one), the loop you wrote is infinite, i will always be <= Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its a known bug in Java 6.  The JIT optimizes the loop incorrectly. I believe more recent versions of Java don't have this bug.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/when-jit-gets-it-wrong.html

Java 6 update 16 is just over two years old. I suggest you update to the latest version Java 6 update 25 if you can't update to Java 7.

BTW Java 6 will be End Of Free Support in a couple of months (Dec 2012)

Comment: Very interesting. I was just about to post the similar finding except I did not really know the root cause of this abnormal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the JVM bug by using Integer.MAX_VALUE-1.