# Java Overflow issues

Tags: java

I wrote the following code, which answers differently when I have printing statement and without it.

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      int j = Integer.MAX_VALUE-100;
      int count = 0;
      for(; j<=i; j++){
        count++;
        //System.out.println(j); // If we remove comment, answer is different
      }
     System.out.println(count + ", " + j + ", " + (j<=i));        
    }
}
```

The answer without print statement is :

```
101, -2147483648, true
```

and with print statement is :

```
15588, -2147468161, true
```

In both the cases, the final condition should return `false`, but it returns `true`. Can anybody explain this.

Comment: If you correct your code, so that `j <= i` is instead `j < i`, then the loop will terminate and I get the same answer regardless of the print statement.

Comment: I think it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793248/for-loop-terminating-early-when-comparing-to-integer-max-value-and-using-system

Comment: @auselen Not sure if it is a duplicate as some seem to see the issue with openJDK 7 whereas the other question was on JDK 6...

Comment: @assylias it is obviously a bug though :) for the print case my jvm even prints random data.

Comment: I checked the byte code, that looks sane, so it must a bug on JIT. (1.6.0_04-b12)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`j <= Integer.MAX_VALUE` is always true by definition. Your loop never ends, in both cases.

If you change this to `j < i`, the loop will terminate and the same answer will be returned regardless of the print statement.

**EDIT**

When testing the code with Netbeans / Oracle JDK 7u9, the loop never ends as expected. However some report that they see the same behaviour as described in the question. @auselen points to [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793248/for-loop-terminating-early-when-comparing-to-integer-max-value-and-using-system) which refers to a bug.

Comment: Yes, needs to be `<` for the loops to terminate. In which case, I get the same answer regardless of the print statement.

Comment: @DuncanJones Yes, in which case it outputs `100, 2147483647, true`, with or without the print statement.

Comment: This doesn't answer why the `println()` statement changes the output though. For me, the `println()` causes the program to loop infinitely, but without it it works fine.

Comment: but with `j <= i` the program does also terminate. why?

Comment: @gefei no it does not. At least not with the code in the question.

Comment: @assylias: Yes, it does running java-7-openjdk-amd64 in Eclipse.

Comment: @Keppil Ah ok my bad - I was not aware of that bug. I'm using Oracle JDK 7u9 and the loop never ends, as expected.

Comment: @assylias the loop terminates for me too, so your answer is wrong. not sure why yet

Comment: @Bohemian My answer is correct - I can't be held responsible for third parties bugs!

Answer (score 3):

It is normal that the final condition is `true` because after the final iteration, `j` will go from `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, hence becoming smaller than `i`.

However, I don't know why putting a print statement would affect the values of the variables... As far as I know, it shouldn't have any side-effects.

Comment: but why does the loop exit at all? j must be greater than MAX_VALUE for the loop condition to be false and the loop to terminate, which should be impossible

Answer (score 0):

The loop finishes when `j` is `<=` to `i`, therefore at the end, `(j <= i)` is true. If you want it to be false, you would have to set `j <= i + 1` in the for loop.

Comment: Sorry. But your statement is wrong. The loop should finish when j<=i is false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get the same results as you.

Without the print statement, I get `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1` and `true`.

The loop actually executes `4294967395` times (change `count` to a `long` to see this):

```
long count = 0; // make this change
```

Output is then:

```
4294967395, 2147483646, true
```

`4294967395` is exactly `Integer.MAX_VALUE - Integer.MIN_VALUE + 100`, meaning it iterates all the way through every `int` value then back up to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` for a *second* time.

Theoretically, the loop should never terminate, because it's impossible for an `int` to exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, however it *does* terminate.

In this case, the count shows that `j` overflows `Integer.MAX_VALUE` *twice*, at which point it is apparently considered greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`!?

Is this a bug in the JVM?

---

If the print statement has a condition to prevent 4 billion printlns:

```
if (j > Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
     System.out.println(count + " " + j);
```

the output changes to this:

```
101 2147483647
230627, -2147253122, true
```

The first line is expected from before the first overflow, but the second count is a mystery to me.