# java loop with Integer.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, integer, long-integer

I have stumble upon such strange code that i don't why??

```
public class CrazyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long val = 0L;
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            val = i;
        }
        System.out.println("val = "+val);

        int kk =Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        System.out.println("kk = "+kk);

        long val2 = 0L;
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            val2 = i;
        }
        System.out.println("val2 = "+val2);
    }
}
```

the strange 1 is "val = " will be various while you run at two times and the value is
"val=493794", "val=675042" why?

the strange 2 is why the "kk = 2147483647" and "val2=2147483645", why the gap value is 2, not 1?

my env is [Mac OS 64bit 10.8.3], the eclipse is [Indigo] , and jdk is [JavaSE6 MacOS default]

Comment: i ran your code and got `val = 2147483646 / kk = 2147483647 / val2 = 2147483646` And we match specs

Comment: same here with same outputs for several times

Comment: Uhm, that is really illogical! If you really see that, this is a bug. Where did you get that code from?

Comment: If its a bug, it doesn't seem very reproducible.

Comment: Try with another JDK, do you obtain the same inconsistent results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [for loop terminating early when comparing to Integer.MAX\_VALUE and using System.out.println](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793248/for-loop-terminating-early-when-comparing-to-integer-max-value-and-using-system)

Comment: Update to Java 7, that'll solve it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer great finding!

Answer (score 0):

You can work around the JVM bug by using Integer.MAX_VALUE-1